# SQL 'Time' C# Equivalent - System.TimeSpan does not work

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

Well, I'm trying to retrieve data from a database, the column name is 'EventTime' with datatype time(7), the following is my C# code:

```
[Column(IsDbGenerated = true)]
public TimeSpan EventTime { get; set; }
```

I've searched around, and it seems like TimeSpan is indeed the equivalent of time, however, it still causes an exception when I try to run that code, all the other columns load fine

Has anyone experienced similar problems?

Edit: Here's a sample of the data from the column "10:34:00"

The only exception details I have available are vague:
"Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."
MSDN specifies that TimeSpan is the appropriate data type here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx?PHPSESSID=lm71lj7i6gj5fjtebtb2srl4n3

Comment: Timespan is simply a duration / time elapsed .. it is not a point in time :) see James Hill's answer

Comment: `it still causes an exception` and the message of the exception is... ?

Comment: TimeSpan gives you an interval, not the time of day.  Mark the answer by James as correct.

Comment: Okay, I finally understood what everyone means by time elapsed, I fixed the datatype in SQL and James answer worked, thanks for the time and patience guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I suggest using [`System.DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx).

```
[Column(IsDbGenerated = true)]
public DateTime EventTime { get; set; }
```

Note: Additional information and a sample of the data in the column would be helpful.

Comment: Hey James, thank you for our answer, it's much appreciate, however that didn't do the trick either, I added some additional information in case it helps (though I doubt it does, sorry for that)

Comment: Okay, I understood what the problem is (thanks to the comments), 
the 'time' datatype in SQL is a range, so it wouldn't do with the data I held
I fixed the datatype in SQL and your answer worked like a charm, thanks!